# Super Simple Proof of Cofactor Expansion

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, laplace-expansion

Is it possible to provide a super simple proof that cofactor expansion gives a determinant value no matter which row or column of the matrix you expand upon? E.g., super simply prove that

$$\det(A) =\sum\limits_{i=1}^k (-1)^{i+j} a_{ij}M_{ij} $$

I say super simple because all the proofs I've seen require knowledge of sign of permutations and esoteric notation that I don't yet fully understand.. I am taking a linear algebra class and our professor didn't prove why this formula gives us the determinant, he just said so, but I'm uncomfortable just memorizing a formula that I don't fully understand. Also, the book I'm using doesn't provide a proof of this theorem either.

Comment: When you say to prove that expression, what "definition" of the determinant can you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should convince yourself that $det(A)=det(A^{T})$ and that swapping two rows of A multiplies the determinant by -1.  Then you can always expand by the 'first' row.